# Passing a python str as LPCSTR to a c++ dll

Tags: python, c++, winapi, dll, lpcstr

I have a simple c++ dll that calls the MessageBox to display text

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define LIBDLL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

LIBDLL void Display(LPCTSTR lpInput) {
    MessageBox(0, lpInput, 0, 0);
}

bool __stdcall DllMain(void* hModule, unsigned long dwReason, void* lpReserved) {
switch (dwReason)
{

case 1:
    break;
case 0:
    break;

case 2:
    break;

case 3:
    break;

}

return true;
}
```

And the Python code only pass a string to the Display in the dll , it looks like this

```
import ctypes
sampledll = ctypes.WinDLL('SampleDll.dll')
sampledll.Display('Some Text')
```

And it only displays the first letter , even if I'm using std::cout

[image: MessageBox output]

How to I make it display the all text I passed to it?

Comment: Please see the [documentation of MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You will see that the parameters required are `LPCTSTR`, not `LPCSTR`.  If you don't know the difference, it's about that time to read up on the differences between ANSI and wide character strings.  So more than likely, you need to pass strings that use wide characters.

Comment: Changed it but still output the same result

Comment: Make sure you are sending the correct string types to the `MessageBox` function.  I don't know Pyhon, and I don't know if the strings you're sending to the DLL function are wide strings.  Bottom line -- you need both your Python code and DLL to agree on the string types being sent back and forth.  So far it seems that isn't the case.  Also, the reason for `std::cout` doing the same thing is for the same reasons.  Use `std::wcout` if you want to see the entire string if the string is a wide string.

Comment: You cannot have an `LPCTSTR` in the public interface of your binary. Its meaning depends on the build environment. If you deploy a binary, you'll want to nail down the ABI. That means: Pick **either** `LPCSTR` **or** `LPCWSTR` and explicitly call `MessageBoxA()` or `MessageBoxW()` to match. You'll still have to make sure that your Python code uses the correct encoding, but at least the expected encoding is fixed (sort of) at the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fix this. Turns out that I have to encode the text before I pass it to dll.

So instead of doing this

```
sampledll.Display('Some Text')
```

It should be done like this

```
sampledll.Display('Some Text'.encode('utf-8))
```